# How to fill new column based on other columns in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe, df, which looks like this:

| Account | check |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Y |
| 10 | Y |
| 10 | N |
| 10 | Y |
| 12 | Y |
| 12 | Y |
| 12 | N |

Now I want to create a result column which looks like this:

| Account | check | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Y | 1 |
| 10 | Y | 1 |
| 10 | N | na |
| 10 | Y | 2 |
| 12 | Y | 1 |
| 12 | Y | 1 |
| 12 | N | na |

The result column is constructed using the account and checks columns. When check is Y the result column should be a count based on the previous value for the account in the result column. For new account numbers the result value should be initialized with na. How do I create the result column in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like this.

I am grouping records by Account and with conditional running sum i am detecting change from Y to N. At the end i am just swapping values for N to N/A

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [
    ("10", "Y"),
    ("10", "Y"),
    ("10", "N"),
    ("10", "Y"),
    ("12", "Y"),
    ("12", "Y"),
    ("12", "N"),
]
columns = ["Account", "check"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("Account").orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())

result = df.withColumn(
    "result", F.sum(F.when(F.col("check") == "N", 1).otherwise(0)).over(window_spec) + 1
).withColumn("result", F.when(F.col("check") == "N", "na").otherwise(F.col("result")))

result.show()
```

My output:

```
+-------+-----+------+
|Account|check|result|
+-------+-----+------+
|     10|    Y|     1|
|     10|    Y|     1|
|     10|    N|    na|
|     10|    Y|     2|
|     12|    Y|     1|
|     12|    Y|     1|
|     12|    N|    na|
+-------+-----+------+
```